# Python File Display

Tags: python, file

I am completely new to Python so I don't know where to start. My requirement seems pretty straight forward. I have a file on a SCO UNIX box which contains a number which is never more than 3 digits. What I need is a program that will read this file and display the number, full screen, on a 800 x 600 resolution monitor. The program then needs to sleep for 60 seconds, then read the file again and display the new number.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I was bored, so here is some code that will get you started:

```
import threading, time
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.exit_fullscreen) # Press Esc to exit full screen mode

        file_name = "./test.txt" # This is the file being read

        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.value_label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable = self.value, font=(None, 40))
        self.value_label.pack(padx = 40, pady = 40)

        t = threading.Thread(target = self.read_value, args = (file_name,))
        t.start()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def exit_fullscreen(self, e):
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)

    def read_value(self, file_name):
        while True:
            with open(file_name) as read_file:
                self.value.set(read_file.read())
            time.sleep(60)

GUI()
```

I find it easier to keep the GUI responsive while running other functions using threading, but here is another method to do it without the use of threading:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.exit_fullscreen) # Press Esc to exit full screen mode

        self.refresh_time = 60 # The refresh time in seconds
        self.file_name = "./test.txt" # This is the file being read

        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.value_label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable = self.value, font=(None, 40))
        self.value_label.pack(expand = True)

        # starts self.read_value with a 100ms delay to give self.root time to start
        self.root.after(100, self.read_value)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def exit_fullscreen(self, e):
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)

    def read_value(self):
        with open(self.file_name) as read_file:
            self.value.set(read_file.read())
        # calls the function again after self.refresh_time (in ms)
        self.root.after(self.refresh_time * 1000, self.read_value)

GUI()
```

Comment: Can you point me to the best resource for information on Tkinter functions and their options?

Comment: I have managed to change the font, font size, background colour & foreground colour. My text is centred within the width of the screen but how do I get it centred within the depth of the screen remembering that we are using this in full screen mode.

Comment: `self.value_label.pack(expand = True)` should work here.

Comment: Added a non-threaded approach, just to give an idea of things you can do with tkinter.

Comment: Doesn't work. The field I am displaying is still at the top of the screen. I need it to be centred within the height of the screen.

Comment: I have sorted it out. What I needed to do was to change the font & change the size to 600. Thanks for your assistance.